# Configure "When a new email arrives (V3)" trigger to filter based on specific word or domain in the From field

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I created a short logic app where the trigger is "When a new email arrives (V3)" and I would like for it to trigger only for emails from a specific domain, let's say **xyz.com**. I know I can use the From parameter, but that requires me to manage list of emails, separated by semicolons.

[image: email trigger]

How could I configure this to trigger only for xyz.com emails?

I tried to use dynamic content but, so far I did not manage to figure it out.

Comment: Filter on the domain and have an if else based on that compared to xyz.com and then continue your logic app

Comment: right, but how do I filter based on the domain? preferably in the "When a new email arrives (V3)" trigger itself..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a trigger condition to the flow.

Although our triggers look a little different, the concept should be exactly the same.  First, you need to access the settings of the trigger ...

[image: Trigger Settings]

... and then you need to add the trigger condition.

In your case, the trigger condition will be like thus ...

```
@contains(triggerBody()?['From'], 'xyz.com')
```

[image: Trigger Condition]